# Installing the python-igraph-0.6 module on Fedora 17

Tags: python, fedora, igraph

I try for some time to install the python-igraph-0.6 module for my EPD-python.
I built the C-core, and following the instruction on various sites I do:

```
/home/joseph/epd/bin/python setup.py build
```

or

```
/home/joseph/epd/bin/python setup.py install
```

and it generates always the same error:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I would have to possible explainations: Either 'gcc' is not working properly (but I already compiled the C-part with ./configure, make, make install) or something is not properly linked somehow.
I already looked at similar posts and installed python-devel packages and so on ...
but nothing changed.

The full output is:

```
[root@joseph python-igraph-0.6]# /home/joseph/epd/bin/python setup.py build
Using default include and library paths for compilation
If the compilation fails, please edit the LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_*
variables in setup.py or include_dirs and library_dirs in 
setup.cfg to point to the correct directories and libraries
where the C core of igraph is installed
()
Include path: /usr/include /usr/local/include
Library path: 
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'igraph._igraph' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include     -I/usr        /local    /include -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local    /include -I/usr/include -I/home/joseph/epd/include/python2.7 -c src/common.c -o     build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/common.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/joseph/epd/include/python2.7 -c src/arpackobject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/arpackobject.o
In file included from src/arpackobject.c:23:0:
src/arpackobject.h:27:27: fatal error: igraph_arpack.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: PS:  'easy_install python-igraph' leads to the same error message.

Comment: PS2: 'yum install python-igraph' installs some older version 0.5.4-4, but it cannot be imported either in the normal system python or in the EPD-python anyway.

Comment: Please include the full output of `python setup.py build` - the line you included is not really informative.

Comment: @Tamás Here is the full output:

Comment: @user1227298 you should have updated your question with information not added an *answer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting indicates that the compiler cannot find the headers required to bind to the C core of igraph. In particular, it is missing a file called `igraph_arpack.h`, but this is not the only one, there would be more had `gcc` continued with the compilation after this message.

The `setup.py` script of the Python interface of igraph relies on `pkg-config` to figure out where to find the headers, but in your system this fails, probably because `pkg-config` itself is not installed. So, I guess that the solution is as follows:

1. Make sure that you run `make install` after having compiled the C core. You claim that you did so, but I thought I'd mention it anyway for sake of completeness.
2. Install `pkg-config` on your system.
3. Check that `pkg-config` knows about the installed C core of igraph by typing `pkg-config --cflags --libs igraph`. If you see a bunch of compiler options printed to the standard output, you are okay.
4. Run `python setup.py install` again. This time it should invoke `pkg-config` successfully, get the required compiler options, and compile the Python interface successfully.

If it still doesn't work (e.g., because you cannot get `pkg-config` to work), you can open `setup.cfg` and edit the `include_dirs` and `library_dirs` variables; the former should point to the folder where the igraph include files are to be found (typically `/usr/local/include/igraph` or `/usr/include/igraph`, depending on where exactly you installed the C core), and the latter should point to the folder where `libigraph.so` is).

Comment: Yes it was a problem with the `pkg-config`. I had to update the path pointing to igraph: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/ ...`. Next, there was the `python-igraph ImportError: /igraph/_igraph.so: undefined symbol: igraph_warning_handler_ignore` error, which you already answered successfully on another blog. Thanks a lot! I hope that you're package does a good job (must be faster than `NetworkX`). You could update the `igraph`-Wiki with those information. This would spare noob-users as me some frustration. Thanks for providing the software and advice!!

Comment: one more comment: I noticed that `yum install igraph` installed a older version `igraph-5x` which starts when typing `igraph` into the command line (using the system python).

Comment: @admins: I don't understand what the problem with this question or comments were. There was a problem and it has been solved! It was helpful. Never mind.